# Formula to automatically sort range of data into groups in different columns by colour?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, sorting

I am an educator trying to find a way to automatically group students into broad groups of 'below' 'at' and 'above'.
My data is more specific (i.e. numerical value between 0 and 30) and I would like to be able to input the specific numerical data and have it automatically sort names into the broader groups.
I would prefer this to happen on the same sheet if possible.
I have already conditionally formatted so that it colour codes, but I would like it to ADDITIONALLY create an extra table.

So far I basically have 'if score between 0 and 3, cell turns red. If between 5 and 8, cell is green, etc.'
I would like a formula that says 'if cell is green, copy matching name into 'at' column, if cell is purple, copy matching name into 'above' column, etc.

I am very new to Google Sheets and am working it out as I go so would love help for this!
I have attached quick sketch of what I'm hoping to achieve: [image]

Comment: Hello! [Take the tour here.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) You should look into google sheet's `FILTER` function [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197).